# Execute functions in a List

Tags: scala

I have Object in scala in which I have defined some functions.

```
Object Sample {
val listFunction = Seq(func1(a,b),func2(p,q))
def func1(a: Int,b : Int) : Int ={
    val c = a+b
    c
  }

def func2(p: Int,q : Int) : Int ={
      val d = p+q
      
    }
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//Want to call the list and execute the functions
ListFunction
}
```

How to call the list in main method and execute it?

Comment: What do you mean with call? If you do `Sample.listFunction` it will execute all the functions to give you the list of results.

Comment: So you want to loop through `listFunction` and execute each function inside it? You just need to do `listFunction.foreach(f => f())` or something like that. Also, where are `a`, `b`, `p`, and `q` defined when you create `listFunction`?

Comment: @user I want execute something like listFunction.foreach(f => f(2,3)) and execute both func1 and func2

Comment: Okay, so what problem are you running into?

Comment: When I'm calling the val d= Example.listFunction.foreach(f => f(2,3)), Error is throwing as 'Int' does not take parameters.

Comment: Oh, I see. You called the functions when defining `listFunction` instead of just writing the function names. Instead of putting in arguments to `func1` and `func2`, just refer to them directly.

Comment: By the way, there are other reasons why your code won't compile - a, b, p, and q aren't defined anywhere (except inside `func1` and `func2`), you don't return anything in `func2`, and your `main` method is outside `Sample`, although I suspect that last one doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
def func1(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
def func2(p: Int, q: Int): Int = p + q
```

Consider the difference between

```
val x: Int = func1(2, 3)            // applied function
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = func1    // function as value
```

So you have to use functions as values as you pass them to the sequence like so

```
val listFunction: Seq[(Int, Int) => Int] = Seq(func1, func2)
```

and then map over the list to apply the functions

```
listFunction.map(f => f.apply(2, 3))
listFunction.map(f => f(2, 3))
listFunction.map(_(2, 3))
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DH7wAfZHSTqMPYKY5msAmg)